# Is it possible to use angular template compiler outside of angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, web

If it's possible, Which classes, interfaces and ... from @angular/compiler are useful? templateAST, templateParser, ... ?

I have just downloaded this from npm, there is some lexer, parser, ASTs, but I need a source to read about it, to help me more, to isolate angular template compiler from angular, just template parser and data binding is important to me, I don't need any more, things like module compiler.